# db2 federation to Netezza

Tags: database, db2, netezza, db2-luw

I want federation from db2 to Netezza.

db2 version is 9.7 on Linux. Just little confusion that can I federate it without installation of Netteza client or I have to first install Nettezza client for it on db2 server.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but I don't think Federation with Netezza sources was supported until DB2 10.1.

Comment: See this 10.1 documentation, which will also answer your question: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.conn.fw.odb.doc/topics/iiynwodb_netzaddt.html

Answer (score 0):

After upgraded database to V10.5, its working now.